# matlab2tikz font size

Tags: fontsize, matlab2tikz

I Latex, how can I change/reduce the font size on a Matlab figure created by using matlab2tikz?

I would like to reduce the font size on the axis numbers, labels, title, legend, etc.

It does not need to be in latex, when using input function, it is also okay if I can use some commands in the Matlab script creating the tikz figure.

E.g., I would like to reduce font size: "Title", "x-label", "y-label", "legend", and the numbers on the x and y axis.

```
plot(1:4)
xlabel('x-label')
ylabel('y-label')
title('Title')
label('A line')

matlab2tikz('Test.tikz', ...
   'height','\figureheight','width','\figurewidth', ...
   'parseStringsAsMath',true);`
```

I Latex:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\setlength\figureheight{2cm}
\setlength\figurewidth{3cm}
\input{Test}
\end{figure}
```

Hope you guys can help me. Thank you in advance.
Best, Peter

**UPDATE:**

For some reason I cannot change ticklabel, either font size or color.

Matlab code:

```
figure;subplot(211);plot(1:10);ylabel('stuff');subplot(212);plot((1:10)*2);
ylabel('stuff');xlabel('other stuff');

matlab2tikz('test.tikz', ...
    'height','\figureheight','width','\figurewidth', ...
      'extraaxisoptions',['xlabel style={font={\color{blue}}},'...
                          'ylabel style={font=\tiny},',...
                          'ticklabel style={font=\color{red}}']);
```

When I include the picture in Latex, the ticklabels does not change color, while xlabel and ylabel do change as desired. Can some one tell me why?

I would like to decrease font size for both all labels (label and ticks on x- and y-axis)

Below is the content of 'test.tikz' file

```
% This file was created by matlab2tikz.
%
%The latest updates can be retrieved from
%  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz
%where you can also make suggestions and rate matlab2tikz.
%
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=0.95092\figurewidth,
height=0.418605\figureheight,
at={(0\figurewidth,0\figureheight)},
scale only axis,
separate axis lines,
every outer x axis line/.append style={black},
every x tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}},
xmin=1,
xmax=10,
xlabel={other stuff},
every outer y axis line/.append style={black},
every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}},
ymin=0,
ymax=20,
ylabel={stuff},
xlabel style={font={\color{blue}}},ylabel style={font=\tiny},ticklabel style={font=\color{red}}
]
\addplot [color=blue,solid,forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   2\\
2   4\\
3   6\\
4   8\\
5   10\\
6   12\\
7   14\\
8   16\\
9   18\\
10  20\\
};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[%
width=0.95092\figurewidth,
height=0.418605\figureheight,
at={(0\figurewidth,0.581395\figureheight)},
scale only axis,
separate axis lines,
every outer x axis line/.append style={black},
every x tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}},
xmin=1,
xmax=10,
every outer y axis line/.append style={black},
every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}},
ymin=0,
ymax=10,
ylabel={stuff},
xlabel style={font={\color{blue}}},ylabel style={font=\tiny},ticklabel style={font=\color{red}}
]
\addplot [color=blue,solid,forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   1\\
2   2\\
3   3\\
4   4\\
5   5\\
6   6\\
7   7\\
8   8\\
9   9\\
10  10\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

Comment: make a super simple matlab plot (3-4 points) so that we can see what you mean by `font size` Is it the legend? Tick labels etc. Othewise please don't expect too much from us to make up an example. Probably you already have an example in your computer so why not making it obvious?

Comment: Thank you for your replay. I cannot see how an example will help illustrate what I look for. As I write I would like to reduce font size on the axis (numbers, ticks), labels, title, legend etc. Thus, I answer your question/concern about that which font I would like to reduce.

Comment: An example would save all of us to type an example try it on Matlab, export it to TikZ, compile that and see if it works and then try a solution. All this to help you which you already did on your own computer.

Comment: Hope above example help

Comment: @etyM Please add the contents of `Test.tikz` to your question and make the LaTeX code complete by adding `\begin{document}`, `\end{document}`, etc. In the Matlab code, did you mean `legend('A line')` instead of `label('A line')`?

Answer (score 7):

`pgfplots` sets up a bunch of styles that determine how axis labels, titles, ticklabels etc. look. These can be redefined by adding options to the optional argument of the `axis` environment. For example, to change the size of the legend to `\tiny`, add `legend style={font=\tiny}`.

`matlab2tikz` allows you to append options to the `axis` with the `extraAxisOptions` parameter, so you could do something like

```matlab
plot(1:4)
xlabel('x-label')
ylabel('y-label')
title('Title')
legend('A line')

matlab2tikz('Test2.tikz', ...
   'height','\figureheight','width','\figurewidth', ...
   'parseStringsAsMath',true,...
   'extraaxisoptions',['title style={font=\Huge},'...
                       'xlabel style={font={\color{blue}\bfseries}},'...
                       'ylabel style={font=\tiny},',...
                       'legend style={font=\scshape},',...
                       'ticklabel style={font=\color{red}}']);
```

to get the (rather silly) result

[image]

Another option is to use one of the predefined styles `small`, `footnotesize` or `tiny`, which is used as e.g.

```
\begin{axis}[tiny,
             ... %any other axis options
```

Note that these also modify the width and height of the plot, as well some other settings, so if added to the end of the options, as they would be with `extraAxisOptions`, they would override your width and height setting. Hence, to use these I think you need to edit the `.tikz` files.

Comment: Thank you very much for your complete answer! However, for some reason my ticklabel do not change color. I would like to change the font size, but nothing is chanced. Can you maybe give a hint on why this is the case? Are there something which may interfere with the `ticklabel` setting in Matlab?

Comment: @etyM I have no idea what your ticklabel settings in Matlab are, nor what code `matlab2tikz` produces, so it is very hard to give any hints. If you could edit your question to include minimal example codes (both from Matlab and `matlab2tikz` would be nice) I can take a look later.

Comment: Alright, see update above. Hope it is as desired.

Comment: @etyM Not really, I meant the Matlab code that creates the plot in the first place, and the complete contents of the `.tikz` file. Your original data is unimportant, you can replace that with e.g. `plot((1:24)*50)`. A minimal example (`figure;subplot(211);plot(1:10);ylabel('stuff');subplot(212);plot((1:10)*2);ylabel('stuff');xlabel('other stuff');`) followed by your `matlab2tikz` invocation works fine here, so I would need more information. I have version 0.4.7 of `matlab2tikz` and 1.11 of `pgfplots`.

Comment: Torbjørn T: pfgplot is also 1.11, but I use matlab2tikz v0.6.0. See update above. Does this information help? 
Once again, thank you for your time/help!

Comment: Torbjørn T: I can tell that the ticklabels change to red when going to the older versio (0.4.7) :-/

Comment: @etyM The problem is caused by the `extra x/y tick label/.append style` lines in the `axis` options, but for some reason I do not get those when running the Matlab code with `matlab2tikz` v0.6. Don't know why that is. My Matlab version is 2012a, I can check with 2014a later.

Comment: Ok, I misremembered, it is 2014b I have, and there `matlab2tikz` doesn't seem to work at all, so I cannot test.

Comment: My Matlab is 2014a. Currently when I use the old version v0.4.7 it seems to work; however, I do not understand why ther newer v0.6.0 does not :/

Comment: @etyM Me neither, I would suggest posting a bug report at https://github.com/matlab2tikz/matlab2tikz